# clojure keeping protocol definition in a separate namespace from implementation

Tags: clojure, namespaces, protocols

I've been trying to build a discipline of separating my protocol definitions into their own namespace, primarily as a stylistic choice.  One thing I don't like about this approach is that since anything a namespace requires is effectively "private" to that namespace, users wanting to call protocol functions from another namespace would have to add a require statement to their code for the protocols.

For example:

**Protocol definition namespace:**

```
(ns project.protocols)

(defprotocol Greet
  (greet [this greeting]))
```

**Implementation namespace:**

```
(ns project.entities
 (:require [project.protocols :as protocols]))

(defrecord TheDude
  [name drink]
  protocols/Greet
  (greet [this greeting]
    (println "The Dude sips a" drink)
    (println greeting)))
```

**Core namespace:**

```
(ns project.core
 (:require [project.protocols :as protocols]
           [project.entities :refer [TheDude]]))

(let [dude (TheDude. "Jeff" "white russian")]
  (protocols/greet dude "not on the rug, man..."))
```

This works just fine, but I don't particularly like that users need to be aware of the need to require `project.protocols` which is really an implementation detail internal to `project.entities`.  In other languages I would just refer to `project.entities/greet` within `project.core` but namespaces don't "export" their required vars in Clojure, they are internal to the requiring namespace only.  I see two obvious alternatives, a third could be using something like Potemkin:

1. Don't put the protocol definitions in a separate namespace, just define them in the same file as the implementation (e.g. `project.entities` here).
2. Inside the implementing file, create vars pointing to each and every protocol function (this is very ugly and just feels wrong, but works).

As an example of number 2:

```
(ns project.entities
 (:require [project.protocols :as protocols]))

(defrecord TheDude 
  [name drink]
  protocols/Greet
  (greet [this greeting]
    (println "not on the rug, man...")
    (println "guess i'll have another " drink)))

(def greet protocols/greet) ; ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

My question, which I suppose is primarily one of preference, is what is the "best practices" (if any) way to handle this sort of separation of concerns?  I realize that adding the `require` in `project.core` is only one more line, but my concern is less about line count and more about minimizing what a user would need to be aware of.

---

**EDIT**:
I think the obvious way to accomplish this is to not expect users to require both namespaces, but to create a core namespace which does that for them:

```
(ns project.core
  (:require [project.protocols :as protocols]
            [project.entities :refer [TheDude]]))

;; create wrapper 'constructor' functions like this for each record in `project.entities`
(defn new-dude 
  [{:keys [name drink] :as dude}]
  (map->TheDude dude))

;; similarly, wrap each protocol method 
(defn greet [person phrase]
  (protocols/greet person phrase))
```

Now any user can just require core, and if they want to extend the protocol to their own record in a different namespace, they can do so and calls to `core/greet` will pick up the new implementations.  Additionally, if there is any pre/post processing to be done, that can be handled in the "higher level" API function `core/greet`.

Comment: What's the point of using a protocol if who calls its functions knows the implementation used?
Just use simple functions

Comment: @rascio What leads you to believe the callers know the implementation here?  The example is not meant to illustrate good usage of protcols as that was not the goal of my question.  I just wanted to provide a concrete "minimum" example of separating protocols into their own namespace versus putting them in the implementing namespace.

Comment: You want to access the protocol defined function from the namespace of the protocol implementer.
Who need to call the function should know the protocol, not the implementer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a program that needs protocols, usually objects are instantiated in some places and consumed (by protocol) in other places.  Perhaps in some cases where that's not so, you didn't really need a protocol anyway.  In effect, is not too common to "require" the namespaces of both a protocol and an implementation of it.  If it happens a lot, it is a code smell.

pete23's answer mentions using the dot syntax to call a record's method without involving the protocol's namespace.  But using the protocol function has some modest advantages.

Absent implementation inheritance, a protocol contains essential ("primitive") functions only.  Such functions are convenient to implement, but not necessarily super-friendly to callers.  The protocol namespace is a great place to add non-primitive accessors, of the sort that you might object-orientedly have declared as a default method on an interface or as an inherited non-abstract method on an abstract base class.  Consumers that use the protocol's namespace can call the primitives and non-primitives alike.

Sometimes a primitive turns out to need pre- or post-processing common to all implementations.  No need to repeat the common stuff in every implementation!  Just lightly refactor:  rename the protocol function from `f` to `-f`, update the implementations, and add a function `f` in the protocol's namespace that wraps `-f` with the necessary pre and post.  The callers do not need any change.

Comment: Agree with all of this, but FWIW the convention for protocol internals is `-f` rather than `f*`. See https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L590 for example.

Comment: The scenario I'm thinking of is that my "implementation" namespace above is library code that has several different records implementing the protocol.  If I have protocols in their own namespace, then users of that library would have to know to require both namespaces, which seems like knowledge they shouldn't need to have (at least until they want to extend the protocol).  


I suppose I could use `core` as the aggregating namespace and provide wrapper functions there for each protocol method  (ala CLJS style), and then just expose the core namespace as the entry point.

Comment: Edited the original post - how does that look?

Comment: Edited answer in observance of the convention pointed out by amalloy.

Comment: Solaxun, better put essential wrappers in the protocol's own namespace, if the protocol might ever be used à-la-carte.  Already, you have warning signals: wrapping "each protocol method", and users who "want to extend".  As for a library's "core", a sage observation from Saint-Exupery: "Perfection is achieved not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away".  I don't think Saint-Exupery had a problem with "helpers" namespaces though.  You can always add "helpers" of arbitrary conveniences for the simple use case.

Comment: Fair point on the potential use of a-la-carte.  Yes wrapping each method is extra work, but allows users to only deal with the core namespace.  More work for me, less for them.  It sounds like the consensus is that it's no big deal to have users require both the implementing namespace and protocol namespace in their code, and that I'm worrying too much about it.  You don't find that clunky though?  Its' more explicit I guess, but just feels kind of wrong.

Comment: Solaxun, another way to look at it is with Hickey's scale of "simple vs easy".  The 2-require alternative covers all cases with one API and less code: it is objectively simple.  Meanwhile, the facade-namespace alternative makes elementary usage easy, but then there is a discontinuity (not simple) where users have to do something different for extended cases.  You can avoid a lot of extra work by favoring "simple" over "easy".  In a nutshell, you have a respectable option of telling users it's clunky for their own good.  (Alan Perlis: "Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon.")

Comment: @BipedPhill One last question then I'll mark as accepted (sorry for the delay!).  What scenario do you imagine as problematic in extended cases?  Users can still extend the protocol to their own types and all the functions in the facade namespace will then apply to those types.  If they choose to call the protocol directly, they can do that as well.  I don't see any conflict from the users perspective here, only more typing for me :)

Comment: Problem scenarios: A user outgrows the facade and must learn the "real" API and either rewrite or suffer a murky mix of facade calls and direct calls. Or, a user outgrows the facade and petitions you to enlarge it. Or, you port to cljc and it prevents the cljs dead-code eliminator from cutting out the "starter" code that people supplanted with their own extensions. There is no harm in a facade that no one discovers is a facade, but if they can tell then it might not have been worth it. Rule of thumb - If beginners can't get started with your true API by copying from the Readme, then refactor.

Comment: Thanks @BipedPhill - I think your first point of outgrowing the facade or needing a mix is more about getting the API right and less about the facade (IMO), which is a risk even with direct calls.  If you got the protocol wrong, you got the facade wrong.  I didn't think about dead coce elimination, that's an interesting point. Thanks again for all your feedback!